# Why are there two Draw Effects buttons in Layer Styling Panel in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style

At 3.10.3, I notice that the *Draw Effects* button is located twice in the Layer Styling window, as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I've spent time testing them, and they both work equally well; that is, they seem to do the exact same things.  One button's functionality is no different than the other.  Additionally, if both are selected, they work together additively (however, the additive effects of the second button could be replicated with a single button).

So I'm curious why there are two buttons. The docs don't discuss this duplication.

In summary, what is the purpose of a second *Draw Effects* button?

EDIT: I also have access to 2.18 which has only one *Draw Effects* button, within the Layer Rendering section.

Comment: @MrXsquared good thought about earlier versions.  I edited my OP accordingly.

Comment: the upper one is per object whereas the lower one draw effects on the whole layer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"Draw effects" beneath the "Layer Rendering" is applied on all features in the layer. The other is used for individual symbol layers.

For example, I have a building layer. I added two symbol layers (marker line + simple fill), I applied different shadow effect for each symbol layer using **upper Draw effects** button, red shadow for red markers, blue shadow for blue area. I also applied a yellow shadow effect using **Draw effects** beneath the **Layer Rendering**.

Note that yellow shadow is applied all symbol layers and if both are selected, they work together additively.

[image]

Comment: Bravo, a very well-presented and detailed answer!  I continue to be very impressed with QGIS and its capabilities.  In this case, the ability to symbolize with great detail and specificity - even down to the individual feature.