# QGIS outer glow effect without self-reinforcement

Tags: qgis, style

I need to have an outer glow on the entire coastline of my map. The way QGIS creates glow effects with a gradient from alpha=1 to alpha=0 creates a problem, that whenever the glow overlaps with itself because of the geometry of a shape (e.g. bays or islands near the coast), it will reinforce its own strength at the overlapping location (see image). This creates an uneven distribution of the glow effect.

[image: Screenshot of glow styling]

I noticed that there are a bunch of different blend modes for the outer glow effect, yet none of them seem to prohibit this kind of self-reinforcement.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably use the wrong "Draw Effects" button. There are two "Draw Effects" options.

You should use the one under "Layer Rendering".

[image]

You may want to review this post: [Why are there two Draw Effects buttons in Layer Styling Panel in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352258/why-are-there-two-draw-effects-buttons-in-layer-styling-panel-in-qgis/)

Answer (score 6):

Choose your glow in Render-Settings for your layer, so it renders for the whole layer, not for each geometry:

[image]

For the example below I am using these settings:

[image]

As you can see:

[image]